# Using countifs in google sheets with AND

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a tracker for how many times I perform different jobs in a month. Currently I am trying to count the number of times I do each job on a weekday (Mon-Fri) and number of times I do each job on a weekend (Sat-Sun).

However, I am struggling to use the countifs function to count the number of jobs I do on weekday/weekend. My current formula looks like this:
`=sum(countifs(A3:AE3,"A",A2:AE2,{"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"}))`

But for some reason its only counting for the first value in the array, e.g. "Mon" only. Can anyone help explain to me what is going wrong?

Example Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1twXyfyG2jlbGwzM_4JS4slnGJUbTFfpX2V2v940LzyA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supplying an array to the *criterion2* argument of COUNTIFS, which by default expects single values to be supplied. To allow an array to be processed and the desired results supplied, wrap your formulae in ARRAYFORMULA, e.g:

```
=arrayformula(sum(countifs(A3:AE3,"A",A2:AE2,{"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"})))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also play trying to use the powerful new GS formulas **REDUCE** and **LAMBDA**

for example if you want to get the number of "A" during weekends:

`=REDUCE(,A2:AE2,lambda(a,c,if(and(OR(c="Sun",c="Sat"),offset(c,1,0)="A"),a+1,a)))`

Or even better :

`=let(job,"A",wkend,true, REDUCE(,A2:AE2,lambda(a,c,if(and(OR(c="Sun",c="Sat")=wkend,offset(c,1,0)=job),a+1,a))))`

This way you just have to change values of 'job' and 'wkend' to get what you want